# React native the development server returned response error code: 500 can't fix

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run android app via visual studio code. I used this commands in the order:

```
npx react-native init imza
npx react-native run
npx react-native run-android
```

but i am getting this error searched for same topics but can't find any solution what can i do ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua1JO.png)

Comment: If you're using node 17, can you try downgrading it to 16 LTS? If it doesn't help, same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804568/error-bundling-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-property-transformfile-of-undef

Comment: @UgurEren yeah, downgrading to 16 LTS fixed my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- Go to your root project
- Open powershell
- Run npm start —–reset-cache
- When it is done, don't close it & open another powershell in your project's root directory at the same time
- Run react-native run-android
```